# Can you have a custom field for paypal subscriptions ? (html)

Tags: html, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

Looking to be able to enter custom amounts for a paypal subscription. 
Is this possible?

Monthly subscription code below is set to $50.00 - I need a custom/blank field. Thanks in advance.

```
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions"/>
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="50"/>
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M"/>
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="************"/>
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="srt" value="12"/>
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="modify" value="2"/>
<input type="hidden" name="usr_manage" value="0"/>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Demo Title"/>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD"/>
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US"/>
<input type="hidden" name="charset" value="windows-1252"/>
<input type="hidden" name="cpp_header_image" value="http://imagedemo.png"/>
<input type="image" src="http://imagedemo.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If client can input amount by themselves, you can update

```html
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="50"/>
```

to

```html
<input type="text" name="a3" value="50"/>
```

then client can change the amount.